# extjs4 combobox in grid with listener, 'select': function(){ doesn't return selection

Tags: extjs4

Here's my combobox in my grid:

```js
{
    id: 'PotentialforInsourcingKV',
    header: 'Potential for Insourcing', 
    width: 30, 
    sortable: true,                      
    dataIndex: 'POTENTIAL_FOR_INSOURCING',
    flex: 1,
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        selectOnTab: true,
        store: [
            ['1', 'Yes'],
            ['0', 'No']
        ],
        lazyRender: true,
        listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
        listeners:{
            scope: this,
            'select': function(combo, rec, idx){
                onUpdateClick(combo, rec, idx)
            }                           
        }
    }
},
```

the 'select' comes up with nothing? My grid is created by extending EXT.panel.Panel when I define the class. I'm using the cellEditing plugin. In the grid, `selModel: 'cellediting'` is set. What can I do?

Thanks in advance!
DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you put the combobox in editor that's why now it will be controlled by cell editor. so you can validate your combo box value by following events of cell editor plugin
Events-->

**beforeedit**( Ext.grid.plugin.Editing editor, Object e, Object options )
Fires before cell editing is triggered. ...

**edit**( Ext.grid.plugin.Editing editor, Object e, Object options )
Fires after a cell is edited. ...

**validateedit**( Ext.grid.plugin.Editing editor, Object e, Object options )
Fires after a cell is edited, but before the value is set in the record. ...

& you can find it in more detail from here....
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing

Comment: This looked really promising but it doesn't work. the combobox listener stops working when I change 'select' to 'edit'. I really need to find the row Index of the the row where the comobox has updated a cell. Thanks for the info...

Comment: thanks for directing me to Cellediting plugin. I added a listener to to it and used the 'beforeedit' event to find the rowIdx.